# Zend 2 Route Hostname regex

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework2, hostname

I want to catch my (optional) subdomain and domain via the route type Hostname in Zend 2.

I'm bad at regexing and unable to find something working correctly.

```
'type' => 'Hostname',
'options' => array(
     'route' => '[:subdomain.]:project_domain',
     'constraints' => array(
          'subdomain' => '??REGEX??',
          'project_domain' => '??REGEX??',
     ),
),
'may_terminate' => false,
```

example 1 :
www.domain.tld => subdomain = www ; project_domain = domain.tld

example 2 :
test.www.domain.tld => subdomain = test ; project_domain = www.domain.tld

example 3 :
domain.tld => project_domain = domain.tld

If someone can help me for this 2 regex patterns, thank you !

Comment: Reading [ZF2 Hostname Route documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-hostname) it looks like you need the constraints regex only if you want to filter the subdomain matches. What constraints do you want?

Comment: example 1 : www.domain.tld => subdomain = www ; project_domain = domain.tld ;;;; example 2 : test.www.domain.tld => subdomain = test ; project_domain = www.domain.tld

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this:

```
'type' => 'Hostname',
'options' => array(
   'route' => '[:subdomain.]:project_domain',
   'constraints' => array(
       'subdomain' => '([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?([^.])',
       'project_domain' => '(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)',
   ),
),
```

It works with my use cases :

- test.domain.tld
- domain.tld
- test1.sub.domain.tld
- asd-asd.sub.do-main.tld

If someone find something not working with, don't hesite to comment.

Thank you.